# sending a JSON using HTTP POST with tornado dont work

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

im using python3 and tornado to send a JSON using a HTTP POST request, like this.

> Server.py

```
@gen.coroutine
def getResponseWS(self, url, contentBody, method='POST'):
    import tornado.ioloop
    import tornado.web
    import tornado.options
    from tornado import gen
    from tornado.httpclient import HTTPClient
    from tornado.escape import json_decode, json_encode
    import json

    http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    headers = {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
           }
    simplejson = json.dumps(contentBody)
    #-------------------------------------------
    # contentBody = {"some_key": "some_value"}
    # url = 'http://some_ip_address:8088/testService'
    #
    baseLogger.info("Data to be send to webservice:%s" % simplejson)
    try:
        request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=url, method=method, headers=headers, body=simplejson)
        response = yield http_client.fetch(request)
        print("-------SERVICE RESPONSE-----------")
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        baseLogger.info("SERVICE RESPONSE:%s" % e)
        contentJson = {}
```

I dont know why it not work, i try the same request on postman and it works perfect and trying the code i get this response:

> Console

```
11-08 16:14:01 BaseLogger  :INFO   IP:[127.0.0.1] -Data to be send to webservice:{"some_key": "some_value"}

-------SERVICE RESPONSE-----------
HTTPResponse(_body=None,buffer=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fda25fad048>,code=200,effective_url='http://some_ip_address:8088/testService',error=None,headers=<tornado.httputil.HTTPHeaders object at 0x7fda45a9d160>,reason='OK',request=<tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest object at 0x7fda25f7db38>,request_time=0.8046760559082031,time_info={})
```

It seems to be working right, but the response should be a json, not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like everything worked. HTTPResponse is an object with attributes like `headers` and `body`, but its string form is not very friendly. You probably want to `print(response.body)` instead of the response object itself. Then you'll see the server response, which you can parse with `json.loads(response.body)`.

Comment: It's weird due to print the whole response dont show any body, but printing response.body show the correct data that i want